# Why webhook never finishes after calling Slack in Azure LogicApps?

Tags: azure-logic-apps, slack

I have LogicApps and trying to do Webhook to Slack.
I understood that webhook is done by giving a single URL to the webbook.
I can successfully post messages to the Slack channel. No errors.

However, the pipeline never completes. It is running forever unless I cancel it. I wonder why?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We discovered that this is due to one of the following causes after testing it in our environment.

- The subscribe-URL for Webhooks :
  We've seen the identical issue you're getting when there isn't a correct link supplied.
- The body of the subscription :
  The similar problem occurs when the structure of the JSON inside the body of the subscription is not properly organized.